# QLPreviewController wont open file at file provider storage

Tags: ios, ios-app-group, fileprovider-extension

I have been trying to manage pdf file in my app and file provider extension, so my app was producing file directly to `-[NSFileProviderManager documentStorageURL]`

And allow my users to open it with `QLPreviewController` with my app, but the `QLPreviewController` wont open it, just stuck on loading forever. Also the same trying to open it in files app.

If I save the file to a normal sandbox path, it's all ok. But then I cant share it in file provider extension.

Is there any particular in file provider storage path?